# Does it make sense to always use asynchronous UDFs in xlwings for updating cells?

Tags: python, excel, xlwings

For xlwings UDFs that return a result that will be written to an Excel cell, does it make sense to always make the UDF asynchronous so that Excel does not freeze while processing the UDF?

Are there situations when not using asynchronous UDFs is better?

https://docs.xlwings.org/en/stable/udfs.html#asynchronous-udfs

I am using Excel 2016 and Windows 10

Comment: xlwings async functions are in an early stage (as of 0.14) and will still need a few iterations to become more stable. You can use it for simple stuff, but as akasolace points out, they only make sense if you wait for a long procedure. So the short answer to your question is "No".

Comment: @Felix, since you're the creator, I take your comment as the answer. THanks for commenting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the real question is when to use asynchronous UDFs. The answer to that question is the same whether or not we are in the context of xlwings. I will quote [MSFT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/excel/asynchronous-user-defined-functions#when-to-use-asynchronous-user-defined-functions):

> Some user-defined functions must wait for external resources. While they wait, the Excel calculation thread is blocked. User-defined functions can run asynchronously. This frees the calculation thread to run other calculations while the user-defined function waits.

Extensive usage of asynchronous function in Excel, will be inefficient but I also *suspect that it might lead to errors and incorrect application state*. This is my opinion based on my experience but not official confirmed so I am looking forward to having expert opinion.

Answer (score 4):

You can use xlOil (disclaimer: I wrote it) to do this. xlOil supports asynchronous functions using both Excel's native async and RTD servers.  The docs for the Python plugin are here: https://xloil.readthedocs.io/en/latest/xlOil_Python/index.html.

The following python module declares an async Excel function `longRunningFunction`:

```
import xloil
import asyncio

@xloil.func
async def longRunningFunction(returnVal, waitTime:int):
    await asyncio.sleep(waitTime)
    return returnVal
```

By default, xlOil uses RTD technology to make this work since Excel's native async is actually not asynchronous with the UI.  This means that if you stop the calculation by interacting with Excel in any way, all native async functions are cancelled.

RTD is asynchronous with the UI, but has some overheads, so should only be used where needed.  It also needs automatic calculation to be enabled to work as expected, i.e. for values to appear in Excel as they are returned.  (Although you could add a delayed call to `Application.Calculate` at the end of your UDF using `xloil.run_later()` to avoid this requirement).  The relative advantages are discussed in the [xlOil Docs](https://xloil.readthedocs.io/en/latest/xlOil_Python/Rtd.html#comparison-between-excel-s-async-and-rtd).

xlOil uses python's `asyncio` library so needs an awaitable function. If the python code you want to call isn't async aware you can always run it in a new process and await the process using `concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor`.

Answer (score 1):

If you need asynchronous functions that work properly with Excel, rather than just writing the values back to Excel using COM later, you should use Excel's asynchronous functions or RTD (real time data) functions. AFAIK, xlwings uses neither of these.

Excel's async functions are different from using a background thread to write a result back to Excel later. They run during the Excel calculation cycle, but allow calculations to run concurrently so other calculations are not blocked on one waiting for IO, for example.

If you have a long running function and you don't want to have to wait for it to return, it is better to use an RTD function that updates once when the result is ready.

Both async and RTD functions are supported by PyXLL (https://www.pyxll.com).

https://www.pyxll.com/docs/userguide/udfs.html#asynchronous-functions
https://www.pyxll.com/docs/userguide/rtd.html

One other option is to use thread-safe functions. These run in a pool of background threads in Excel. If you have functions that can run concurrently (i.e. they release the GIL for IO or CPU intensive tasks) then this is a simple way of improving the performance of your sheets.

To mark a function as thread-safe with PyXLL, you just specify "thread_safe=True" when registering the function, eg:

```
from pyxll import xl_func

@xl_func(thread_safe=True)
def my_thread_safe_function():
    pass
```